# How can I parse JSON Array Using Retrofit and GSON?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I have learnend how to parsing JSON objects via Retrofit Gson but I need to parse a full JSON array via Retrofit Gson.

I need to parse the following :

```
"{\n" +
        "  \"snappedPoints\": [\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      \"location\": {\n" +
        "        \"latitude\": -35.2784167,\n" +
        "        \"longitude\": 149.1294692\n" +
        "      },\n" +
        "      \"originalIndex\": 0,\n" +
        "      \"placeId\": \"ChIJoR7CemhNFmsRQB9QbW7qABM\"\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      \"location\": {\n" +
        "        \"latitude\": -35.280321693840129,\n" +
        "        \"longitude\": 149.12908274880189\n" +
        "      },\n" +
        "      \"originalIndex\": 1,\n" +
        "      \"placeId\": \"ChIJiy6YT2hNFmsRkHZAbW7qABM\"\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      \"location\": {\n" +
        "        \"latitude\": -35.280960897210818,\n" +
        "        \"longitude\": 149.1293250692261\n" +
        "      },\n" +
        "      \"originalIndex\": 2,\n" +
        "      \"placeId\": \"ChIJW9R7smlNFmsRMH1AbW7qABM\"\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      \"location\": {\n" +
        "        \"latitude\": -35.28142839817933,\n" +
        "        \"longitude\": 149.1298619971291\n" +
        "      },\n" +
        "      \"originalIndex\": 3,\n" +
        "      \"placeId\": \"ChIJy8c0r2lNFmsRQEZUbW7qABM\"\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      \"location\": {\n" +
        "        \"latitude\": -35.28193988170618,\n" +
        "        \"longitude\": 149.13001013387623\n" +
        "      },\n" +
        "      \"originalIndex\": 4,\n" +
        "      \"placeId\": \"ChIJ58xCoGlNFmsRUEZUbW7qABM\"\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      \"location\": {\n" +
        "        \"latitude\": -35.282819705480151,\n" +
        "        \"longitude\": 149.1295597114644\n" +
        "      },\n" +
        "      \"originalIndex\": 5,\n" +
        "      \"placeId\": \"ChIJabjuhGlNFmsREIxAbW7qABM\"\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      \"location\": {\n" +
        "        \"latitude\": -35.283139388422363,\n" +
        "        \"longitude\": 149.12895618087012\n" +
        "      },\n" +
        "      \"originalIndex\": 6,\n" +
        "      \"placeId\": \"ChIJ1Wi6I2pNFmsRQL9GbW7qABM\"\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      \"location\": {\n" +
        "        \"latitude\": -35.284728724835304,\n" +
        "        \"longitude\": 149.12835061713685\n" +
        "      },\n" +
        "      \"originalIndex\": 7,\n" +
        "      \"placeId\": \"ChIJW5JAZmpNFmsRegG0-Jc80sM\"\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "  ]\n" +
        "}"
```

I need the lat and longs only.

Here is the method I know to parse JSON Objects via Retrofit GSON

```
package com.example.akshay.retrofitgson;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 9/6/2015.
 */
public class gitmodel {
    @SerializedName("latitude")
    @Expose
    public String latitude;
    @SerializedName("longitude")
    @Expose
    public String longitude;

    public void setLatitude(String latitude)
    {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
    public String getLatitude()
    {
        return latitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(String longitude)
    {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getlatitude()
    {
        return  latitude;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need the lat/longs only, but the easiest thing to do is to just set up your POJO to get everything, then extract the lat longs from the POJO. You can even design the deserialized object to hide the inner object if you want. In the case of your JSON, this is quite easy, just do this:

```
public static class SnappedPoints {
  private List<Point> snappedPoints;

  public String toString() {
    return snappedPoints.toString();
  }
}

public static class Point {
  private Location location;

  public double getLatitude() {
    return location.getLatitude();
  }

  public double getLongitude() {
    return location.getLongitude();
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "{" + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude() + "}";
  }
}

public static class Location {
  double latitude;
  double longitude;

  public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
  }
  public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
  }
}
```

You can see this in action by simply doing this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(new Gson().fromJson(json, SnappedPoints.class));
}
```

Or, in the case of Retrofit, something like this:

```
public interface MyRetrofitAPI {
  @GET("/path/to/json")
  void getSnappedPoints(/* arguments */, Callback<SnappedPoints> callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit uses the [Gson library](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) to serialise Json responses. As long as you have a model class setup correctly, you can tell Gson to try and serialise the json into an instance of that model class. Your code should look something like the following:

```
String json; // retrieved from file/server
MyObject myObject = new Gson().fromJson(json, MyObject.class)
```